# How to find the frequency of seasonality from statistics model?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am working with data collected over a period of 7 days that are unequally placed. I find out whether or not there is any seasonal component using the following:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

result = seasonal_decompose(data, model='multiplicative')

fig = result.plot()
```

Now looking at the seasonal component, I find it periodic and I want to find out the frequency. How do I do that?

The documentation of `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose()` returns an object where seasonal is an attribute and its a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Your result has a number of methods. Take a look at result.seasonal for the found seasonal component and its frequency.

Comment: Yes I did that. Result.seasonal is a pandas dataframe which looks like this.                                           Energy Production
DATE  
1939-01-01  1.001239
1939-02-01  0.998559
1939-03-01  1.000259
1939-04-01  1.000925
1939-05-01  0.999783                                                 Cant find the frequency.

Comment: These are the seasonal factors. The moment the factors repeat, is the period of the seaonal component.